# PDF File Zip in Memory Stream Showing not supported file or damaged My Code attached

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, memorystream, c#-ziparchive

I have pdf file in directory that can be open successfully. I am actually changing into byte[] and zip it in memory stream and return it.

I got all files as zipped but when i am opening files getting error

> "File can not be open either it has not supported type or file is damage"

I am changing pdf file to byte[],

```
ArrayList PDFbyteList = new ArrayList();

byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop\" + PdfFile);
PDFbyteList.Add(bytes);
```

Then I change it to zip using memory stream,

```
public FileResult DownloadMultiplePDFFiles(List<FileResult> list)
{
    int count = list.Count();
    byte[] file1;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            file1 = ObjectToByteArray(PDFbyteList[i]);
            string name = list[i].FileDownloadName.Split('.')[0];
            name = name + ".pdf";
            var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(name, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
            using (var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open()) zipStream.Write(file1, 0, file1.Length);
            file1 = null;
        }
        //return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", "Reports.zip");
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", "Reports.zip");
    }
}
```

Parameter list having content-type , file name and bytes. I am taking only file name from here and bytes from array list. Well content type in parameter list is "application/octet-stream".

I tried with "application/octet-stream" as well as "application/zip" having same error.

Comment: @Hans Kesting i have alot of files i am saving them all and later using them for generating zip file thats why i am using it in Array List

Comment: never mind, I misunderstood that line

Comment: In C#, you should pretty much **never** use an ArrayList, as it exists now only for backwards compatibility and certain legacy interop situations. Use a strongly-typed `List<T>` instead... in this case `List<byte[]>`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably won't help, but I made some revisions:

```
public FileResult DownloadMultiplePDFFiles(IEnumerable<FileResult> files)
{
    using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);    
    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop\" + file.FileDownloadName);
        string name = $"{file.FileDownloadName.Split('.')[0]}.pdf";
 
        var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(name, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
        using var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open();
        zipStream.Write(file1, 0, file1.Length);
    }
    //return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", "Reports.zip");
    return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", "Reports.zip");
}
```

Comment: @KJ it's doubtful they want every file in that folder, or even every PDF file. It seems like they're using the all users Desktop as temporary file dump for pdf uploads for some reason, which might mix files from several sessions/users. Using `Tar` would also write the bytes to disk first, which is an extra set of IO (slower).